# Cannot download latest version of a file in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, download, python-requests

I have gone through so many `requests` and `urllib` tutorials it's almost criminal, but I can't download the latest version of a file for some reason.

Here is what happens:

1. It downloads the latest version of `bglug.py` successfully. Everything works like a charm.
2. I update `bglug.py` on GitHub to show the latest details.
3. When I run the updating mechanism again, it doesn't fetch the latest version of the file, but I know it does get the file because I set it up to delete the file first (just for testing purposes) and when I check, the file is there.
4. And it still won't download the latest version until the next day or so!

Is this server-side caching? Does Python/`requests` have a web cache that I have to clear in order to get the latest version of the file?

My code is as follows:

```py
import requests, os

os.remove("bglug.py")

url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TheTechRobo/bglugwatch-cleanslate/master/bglug.py"

r = requests.get(url, stream=True)

with open("bglug.py", "wb") as Writefile:

    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):

        if chunk:

            Writefile.write(chunk)
```

Does anyone else have the same problem? Thanks!

Comment: how can we verify / know when the file content has changed?

Comment: why u no git, instead of scraping github?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle This is just during test run, so I just use `cat`.

Comment: @garglblarg I was using git, but because of how git stores files the filesize was getting big.

Comment: @TheTechRobo36414519 It looks like this is just a part of how GitHub works with the raw files. It takes time for the data at raw.githubusercontent.com to update to match the files at github.com. I ran some tests myself and figured this out.
Basically, there's nothing you can change in your code for this "caching" to go away. This is not part of Python or `requests`.

Comment: @NoahBroyles Is there any other link that is similar to raw.githubusercontent.com? Thanks for the answer! :)

Comment: @TheTechRobo36414519 Not that I know of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@NoahBroyles said that there is nothing I can do as `raw.githubusercontent.com` takes time to update. Therefore, users using my program may have slightly late results, but I could work around that by, every time I commit, pushing that commit onto a website and then making `requests` crawl *that*. Thank you @NoahBroyles so much! :) :)